# Issue with Javascript on IOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I have a very confusing case tonight!

So I'm making a chat bot (kinda) with Java Script. It's made to look like an old school OS.

Im adding a chat command which the user says "What country do you live in", it then responds "[Australia]". I tested this on my desktop, all was good! I then ran this on my iPad, and it brought up my error prompt, I then directly copied and pasted (Universal Clipboard for Apple devices) the Mac command into the IOS prompt and it still failed. I am very confused as to why this would be. Any help would be appreciated. NOTE: I am running IOS 14 Beta on my 2 trial devices, however I tried it on a non IOS 14 device (13) still same issue. Also note, punctuation and capitalisation shouldn't matter due to the filter placed in the JS. But that may very well be my problem.

**WEBSITE:**
https://sam-neale.github.io/Net-OS/
**Command in question:** What country are you from

```js
var prevTextCache;
var prevTextCacheC;
var prevTextCacheF
var scrn = document.getElementById("compscrn");
var d = new Date();
var t = d.getTime();
function cacheTextRunProgram(){
    //Cache Text
    prevTextCache = scrn.value;
    prevTextCacheC = prevTextCache.toUpperCase();
    prevTextCacheF = prevTextCacheC.replace(/[.,\/#!$’‘%\^&’\*;:{}=\-_'`~()]/g,"");
    console.log("textCached");
    //Run a program
    if (prevTextCacheF == "HI" || prevTextCacheF == "HEY" || prevTextCacheF == "HELLO"){
        scrn.value = prevTextCache + " [Hey there!]";
        console.log("Ran command");
    }else if (prevTextCacheF == "WHATS THE TIME"){
        scrn.value = prevTextCache + " [" + d + "]";
        console.log("Ran command");
    }else if (prevTextCacheF == "WHATS YOUR NAME"){
        scrn.value = prevTextCache + " [My Name is Net Bot]";
        console.log("Ran command");
    }else if (prevTextCacheF == "WHATS YOUR AGE" || prevTextCacheF == "WHEN WERE YOU BORN"){
        scrn.value = prevTextCache + " [I was made on 14 July 2020]";
        console.log("Ran command");
    }else if (prevTextCacheF == "WHAT COUNTRY ARE YOU FROM"){
        scrn.value = prevTextCache + " [I was made in Australia]";
        console.log("Ran command");
    }else{
        scrn.value = prevTextCache + " [Sorry I don't understand]";
        console.warn("Ran into issue running command command, Code: 0001");
    }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=VT323&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "VT323";
    background-color: black;
}
textarea{
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    border:none;
    background-color: black;
    color: green;
    font-family: "VT323";
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    outline: none;
}
button{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border:none;
    color: white;
    height: 20%;
    font-size: 20px;
}
button:active{
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Net OS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
 <textarea rows="30" id="compscrn" value="demo"></textarea>
 <button onclick="cacheTextRunProgram()">Run Function</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i try on desktop and always say:  [Sorry I don't understand]

Comment: 'What country do you live in' without extra lines.

Comment: same issue. sorry for off topic

Comment: Ok now Im confused even more, I literally copied the most up to dat code from my local git, (no commits/pushes needed) and pasted it in the program. Error, so now I'm really confused

Comment: And... the local version (version stored on my computer works) and the one on the website doesn't. So its a GitHub issue I think?

Comment: No is "Human" issue :) is not : _What country do you live in_   but _WHAT COUNTRY ARE YOU FROM_

Comment: I updated that in the original questions

Comment: Are you sure is not that the 'issue' on iphone?

Comment: TBH I have no clue, Originally the issue was IOS specific, as both the local and website versions were working, then magically out of no where the website version also stoped working, despite the local working.

Comment: in the local version it was probably the sentence you wrote earlier. however test it now with the correct phrase

Comment: And suddenly the website works now. WHAT IS GOING ON!

Comment: is work because you insert the right phrase

Comment: No, I was using the phrase used in the code all along, I accidentally put the phrase incorrectly in the question, but after you noticed I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is a train wreck, I made no changes and magically, IOS works now.

Summary:
Question Asked when local version on Mac was working, and website on Mac was working, but website on IOS was broken.
Then the website on Mac was broken.
Then out of no where, website on Mac was working,
and then website on IOS was working.

I believe this was github's fault, due to at one point the local version working but website not. Thanks for all the help. Im gonna go to bed cause my brain just broke.

Comment: *Not true I made one change early on, with me leaving some accidental code for trying to fix the problem, but still after that was removed it still was broke